# NodeJs приходит пустое тело запроса

Tags: node.js, form, express

Добрый день! Имеется форма вида:

```
form(method="POST", action="/", onsubmit="validate(this); return false;")
           input(id="button", class="normalButton", type="submit", name="loginPlayer", value="Вперед!")
```

Функция `validate(this)` проверяет ajax'ом форму. Далее происходит ее отправка:

```
if (response.loginPlayer == 'notLogin') {
    form.submit();
}
```

, где `form` - переданная в функцию переменная `this`. Опытным путем выявлено, что форма отправляется на сервер заполненная. Но при этом, при попытке вывести тело запроса:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Выводится пустое тело `{}`. В чем мб проблема?

Comment: Покажите код, где вы конфигурируете объект  app.  Какие middleware вы используете?

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
 secret: 'cookie_secret',
 resave: true,
 saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(express.static('templates'));                                                              var app = express(); http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {});app.set('port', config.get('port'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');`

Comment: Тут вроде все в порядке. Как вы выяснили, что форма отправляется?  Могли бы показать тело запроса и значение заголовка Content-Type

Comment: Тело: `console.log(req.body);` Результат: `{}`. Заголовок: `console.log(req.headers["content-type"]);`. Результат: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Насчет формы: тем же способом через консоль вывел ее: `console.log(form.elements)`

Comment: Я имел в виду, посмотреть, что отправляет браузер. Сделать это можно в Инструментах разработчика. Ну или использовать что-то типа Fiddler

Comment: Каким образом это увидеть/понять/ощутить в инструментах? Значение переменной?

Comment: Если у вас Chrome, то во вкладке Network вы должны увидеть все запросы вашей страницы. Двойной щелчок по запросу выведет детальную информацию (заголовки и т.д.)

Comment: В Form Data ничего нету.

Comment: Ну вот, серверная часть тут ни при чем. Нужно разбираться с клиентской частью (html и js)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Однако, вопрос все равно не решен. Мне начинает казаться, что дело в ajax'е. Т.е. `var xhr = getXmlHttp();
    // отправка данных на сервер
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xhr.readyState != 4) {
            return;
        }

        if (xhr.status != 200 && xhr.status != 0) {
            alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
        } else {
            // проверка пришедших данных
            form.submit();
        }`

Comment: Думаю вопрос не актуален. Но похоже стоило использовать POST запрос, а не GET.